# update record outside of namespaced admin [rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, admin

I have a named spaced admin in my app, where you can CRUD a client, this works great.
Outside of the admin within the app the @current_user has the opportunity to edit the client's address.

I am not sure how to access this and persist the new update to the database.  this is what I have so far

products_controller.rb (where the partial is rendering from)

```
class ProductsController < ActionController::Base
    layout "application"
    def index
        @products = Product.all
    end

    def show
        @products = Product.all
        @current_user = Client.find_by(id: session[:client])
    end
end
```

_overlay_checkout.html.erb (this populates a form with the clients address from the db, and if its not updated they can change it.)

```
<%= simple_form_for([:admin, @current_user], :url => edit_admin_client_path) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :address %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :address_line_2 %><br />
      <%= f.select(:state, options_for_select(us_states, "CA")) %> <br />
      <%= f.text_field :zipcode %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :city %><br />
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

im unsure how I can update this record, ... without being in the admin section of the app, .. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've done in situations like this is to specify @submit_url as an instance variable in my controller action.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
 def show
   @submit_url = client_path(@client)
 end
end
```

You can can pass this variable to your form_for call like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for([:admin, @current_user], :url => @submit_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :address %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :address_line_2 %><br />
  <%= f.select(:state, options_for_select(us_states, "CA")) %> <br />
  <%= f.text_field :zipcode %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :city %><br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If the @submit_url is not nil then the form action will be set to the value of the @submit_url otherwise it will get set to the resource based route that you specified. This means that in Admin Controller will not need to be changed at all. Just the alternate controller (in this case products_controller) where you want the submission of the form to go someplace other than the auto generated resourceful route.